# Netbeans: Auto Format - Remove Space From PHP Shorthand Code <?=

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

In the red circle in the image below,
using auto format adds a space between = and $.
How do you remove that space so that
it looks like `<?=$foo on auto format?`

Additional question: How do you disable those green highlights
(circled in green) for HTML code? What does those highlights mean anyway?

[image]

Add

Comment: Why? `<?= $foo; ?>` looks much better. And please write just one question at a time.

Comment: The green is simply highlighting the attribute properties. It's good, because if you left out the second " after the attribute value, it would highlight an obnoxious amount of stuff in green and you'd (hopefully) realize that you forgot to close the value with a second "

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - I prefer <?=$foo;?> because <?= $foo; ?> looks like there's an unwanted space. It becomes too much space in this example <?= ' ' . $foo . ' ' ?>

Comment: @ImportedNoob - That's a good feature but it's also distracting at the same time, anyway to disable that?

Comment: @IMB: You have a redundancy. "I prefer less space because putting the space in makes it look like there's a space." As for your rationale, it sounds like you're reading PHP wrong. Writing ugly syntax to work-around that is so backwards.

Comment: write `<?= " $foo " ?>` not `<?= ' ' . $foo . ' ' ?>`

Comment: @ImportedNoob Single quote is faster than double.
But then that's just a not so realistic example, but you get the point. I just want <?=$foo?> and not <?= $foo ?> :-)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Well "ugly" is in the eye of the beholder

Comment: @IMB: I am the beholder, and I say that it's ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans has fixed this issue at least in version `7.1.2` (possibly earlier but definitely not on 7.0.1 ).

To fix go to: Tools > Options > Formatting > PHP > Spaces > Uncheck `After Short PHP Tag` and `Before Close PHP Tag`